# problem with twint while using specific time

Tags: web-scraping, twitter, google-colaboratory, sentiment-analysis, twint

we are trying to get data from 2021 and we have a problem with the month, which is we can't get the all month in 2021, but we only got the recent month and it just few of tweets. (sorry for my bad english)

```
import twint
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
c = twint.Config()
c.Search = '"covid" lang:id'
#c.Limit = 25000
c.Limit = 10000
c.Since = "2021-01-01" 
c.Until = "2021-12-31"
c.Store_csv = True
c.Output = 'drive/My Drive/skripsi2/datatwittercovid.csv'

twint.run.Search(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to include until:2021-12-31 since:2021-01-01 in the c.Search object

```
c.Search = '"covid" lang:id until:2021-12-31 since:2021-01-01'
```